# Merging sorted integer arrays (without duplicates)

Tags: python, performance, array, functional-programming

I have written a Python function called `merge_arrays` which takes two  lists and returns the new list merge without duplicate.
The function works as expected, but my code very complicated, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it.
Below is my current implementation:

```py
def update_if_new(d, results, element):
    if element not in d:
        results.append(element)
        d[element] = True
        
def merge_arrays(first, second): 
    seen = dict()
    results = []
    i, j, m, n = 0, 0, len(first), len(second)
    
    while i < m and j < n:
        x, y = first[i], second[j]
        if x < y:
          update_if_new(seen, results, x)
          i += 1
        else:
          update_if_new(seen, results, y)
          j += 1
          
    for residual in first[i:] + second[j:]:
        update_if_new(seen, results, residual)
            
    return results
print(merge_arrays([1,2,3],[5,7,1]))
#[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

I'm seeking suggestions for improvements in the code to make it more efficient and reduce the execution time.
Any tips or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [two-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm).

## preconditions

```
merge_arrays([1, 2, 3],
             [5, 7, 1])
```

I was a little surprised to see that non-monotonic `1` tacked on at the end.

Recommend that you insist the caller presents only `sorted( ... )` arrays,
or that you call timsort yourself, perhaps before calling a private helper.

---

## unique

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
is happy to help you discard repeated entries from sorted input.
It costs O(N) linear time and no additional storage.

Or perhaps you'd rather spend O(N) storage to construct e.g. `set(first)`,
at similar cost to the `seen` dict you've been maintaining.

Consider writing a two-way merge generator
which will `yield` monotonic array entries.

---

## use builtins

The simplest solution would look like this.

```
def merge_arrays(first: list[int], second: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return sorted(set(first + second))
```

Depending on details of your data and required performance,
you might want a few tweaks.
For example, initially de-dup'ing two separate sets and
then combining those smaller results,
destructively running `.sort()` on caller's list in-place,
that sort of thing.

Comment: It is not necessary to specify types in Python because Python is not a statically typed language

Comment: That's true. But it is a kindness to the Gentle Reader, offering a clue about what will come back. We might accept `list[tuple]` instead. Or even `list`, though that is vague enough that it compels us to write a """docstring""" explaining what caller should expect. Strictly all we need for _this_ implementation is an Iterable, though that precludes certain techniques such as doing a destructive `.sort()` in-place.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If you throw all the elements into a `set`, you don't need sorted inputs.  (But `set` itself is unordered, and `dict` preserves insertion order rather than using keys to order, unlike C++ `std::map` (typically a red-black tree)).  To avoid doing the full work of sorting, you could use a set to check for and remove duplicates while doing a merge.  But then you'd probably have to loop over elements one at a time, so probably slower in CPython than what you're doing with `set()` and `sort()`.

Comment: I'd say that `list[int]` is so strict type here that it should be either omitted (in simple code) or replaced with real constraints (`Sequence` of typevar bound to a protocol with `__hash__` and `__lt__` OR `__gt__`, similar to definition of [`sorted`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/3c872ca8fd875f2dc5fe5f5d771e35c58390cd0e/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1775) in typeshed, but with additional `__hash__` requirement). Why not let this function merge list of strings or list of tuples? If you replace list concatenation with set union, you can also have `Iterable` instead of `Sequence`.

Answer (score 8):

The suggestions by @J_H are excellent, as usual.

From an algorithmic perspective, though, a two-way merge is a useful exercise, so I think it is valuable to keep to the original algorithm.

#### Be clear about the functionality

The name `merge_arrays` fails to carry essential information:

- That the inputs should be sorted.
- That the outputs will then be sorted.
- That the outputs will be deduplicated.

#### Be clear about the input/output

Type annotations are the modern way, a docstring is always useful regardless. In any case, it's best to be clear about what goes in and what comes out.

Your use of indexes requires a `list` (or similar) as input, and you return a list.

#### Lazy wins the day

It is a frequent task to have to return the first n elements of something, or the n-th smallest element.

Using your function for such a task will result in building a list of *all* elements, and *then* extracting the first n or looking at the n-th. It's rather inefficient.

In general, it is best to be lazy:

- Do not do work that the caller may not care for.
- Do not prematurely allocate a giant data-structure that the caller may not care for.

In this case, returning a generator would be best.

#### Lazy wins the day (bis)

Similarly, forcing the user to construct two lists just so they can be fed into the algorithm which will only pick one element at a time is overkill.

Ideally, you would accept iterables instead.

#### Deduplication does not require a set.

Since the inputs are sorted, knowing whether an element should be appended to the array only requires looking at the last element of the array.

#### Deduplication is orthogonal

Your function fails the Single Responsibility Principle:

- It performs a two-way merge.
- It *also* deduplicates.

It is best to split the two operations into two functions, letting the caller decide whether they want deduplication, or not.

#### Putting it all together

```py
def dedup_sorted(input):
    """Removes duplicates from a sorted iterable

    Returns an iterable of sorted elements, without duplicates.
    """
    input = iter(input)

    try:
        last = next(input)
        yield last
    except StopIteration:
        return

    for e in input:
        if e == last:
            continue

        last = e
        yield e

def merge_sorted(left, right):
    """Merges two sorted iterables into one sorted iterable

    Duplicates are preserved. No guarantee is made as to the order in which
    duplicates are yielded.
    """
    sentinel = object()

    left = iter(left)
    right = iter(right)

    x = next(left, sentinel)
    y = next(right, sentinel)

    while x is not sentinel and y is not sentinel:
        if x <= y:
            yield x

            x = next(left, sentinel)
            continue

        yield y

        y = next(right, sentinel)

    if x is not sentinel:
        yield x

    for x in left:
        yield x

    if y is not sentinel:
        yield y

    for y in right:
        yield y
```

The two functions are algorithmically optimal, performing a single pass over the data -- hence guaranteed O(N) -- and no more than N comparisons on the elements.

Furthermore, they can be chained together at minimal cost, so that your original function is equivalent to:

```py
list(dedup_sorted(merged_sorted(_, _)))
```

Comment: `dedup_sorted([None])` returns an empty list. It's probably better to instantiate `last` with a unique sentinel like `object()`.

Comment: @JAD: Thanks for the tip! Could the same be applied to `merge_sorted`?

Comment: @MatthieuM: given that `None < 3` throws an exception that '<' is not supported between instances of NoneType and int and that merge_sorted implies sortability, I'd argue that None is acceptable to use and that the type should be something like Iterable of numbers which precludes [as much as python types actually preclude] passing None (or a whole lot of other things that also aren't sortable in python, e.g. ['3', 3]

Comment: Rather than introduce an arbitrary sentinel, I would create a dedicated iterator `itr = iter(input)`, then `last = next(itr)` (returning if `next` raises an exception) and `for e in itr`.

Comment: @chepner: That's a good point. A bit more verbose, but avoids concerns of whether the sentinel could compare equal in some situations.

Comment: FYI, instead of using `None`, here's the standard idiom for creating a sentinel which your caller _definitely_ won't be passing in to you: `sentinel = object()`. The object allocator guarantees us a unique address. And then we can test whether `x is sentinel`.

Comment: @J_H: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote except the last part: deduplication and merging are _not_ orthogonal. Yes, you can separate them, but only by doing extra work (and, in particular, extra comparisons between elements). The two-way merge already requires comparing elements from the two inputs to determine which one should come first, so you get deduplication essentially for free (assuming, of course, that the input sequences have themselves been sorted and deduplicated) just by skipping one of the elements if the comparison says they're equal.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The OP's code does not seem to assume that the inputs are deduplicated. And yes, there's a minor efficiency gain in doing everything at once... I'd rather focus on correctness and composability _first_ and only address minor efficiency concerns if they prove worth it. Remember Knuth, "Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil".

Comment: Your `dedup_sorted` drops the first element from the input (and all subsequent equal elements too).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: That's what I get for editing without retesting :) Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not document what's expected of the input:
(ascendantly) *ordered lists* (mentioned in the title, only).

Names not to be used externally (especially "global" ones) should begin with an underscore: `_update_if_new()`.
Which looks introduced to avoid some potential code duplication -
I think this can be achieved more simply.

```
    while i < m and j < n:
        x, y = first[i], second[j]
        if x < y:
            element = x
            i += 1
        else:
            element = y
            j += 1
    if element not in s:
        results.append(element)
        s.add(element)  # d[element] = True
```

(Has the code from `update_if_new()` been duplicated in `merge_arrays()` originally, indented 2 places as indentation grew unwieldy?)

As the sequences are required to be ordered, you don't need a set for uniqueness - using a `dict` is uncalled for logically.
Without type hinting, borrowing liberally from the notably clean code in this [answer](/a/241527) by AJNeufeld:

```
def merge_arrays(first, second):
    """ Return a new list containing in non-decreasing order
        the values from both non-decreasing sequences first & second,
        except values from second already occurring in first.
    """
    try:
        left_iter = iter(first)
        left = next(left_iter)
    except:
        return list(right)
    try:
        right_iter = iter(second)
        right = next(right_iter)
    except:
        return list(left)
    #
    ascending = []
    try:
        while True:
            if left < right:
                ascending.append(left)
                left = next(left_iter)
            else:
                if left != right:  # don't append equal "right" values
                    ascending.append(right)
                right = next(right_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        if left > right:
            ascending.append(left)
            ascending.extend(left_iter)
        else:
            ascending.append(right)
            ascending.extend(right_iter)
    #
    return ascending


if __name__ == "__main__":
    help(merge_arrays)
    a, b = [1,3,3,4,5,7], [1,2,3,5,6,7]
    print("merging", a, "and", b, "- note in-list duplication")
    print(merge_arrays(a, b))
```

(One problem with stating *items with unique key values from multiple sources* is it does not specify what to do with keys occurring in more than one source:

- exclude them entirely?
- include exactly one?
  Which?)

Answer (score 1):

How to find the fastest existing algorithm for sorting and merging?

Seeing how `sorted()` and `set()` in Python are implemented, and perhaps rephrasing them might be a good exercise. Visualise, play, investigate.

You can also use existing functions, they make your code stronger. Perhaps refactoring these implementations might be something to look into.

```py
sorted(set(first + second))
```

```py
sorted(set(first).union(second))
```

What is the purpose of your optimisation? Is this is an exercise in optimisation algorithm writing?

I don't know if the following is a good solution or not:

```py
>>> a = [3, 2, 1]
>>> b = [5, 3, 2]
>>> sorted(*[({*a}|{*b}])
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Using only `set()` seems to sort a few integers, but it doesn't sort a high number of elements.

Comment: (I' expect `set(a)` rather than `{x for x in a}` or `{*a}`.)

Comment: Thank you @greybeard, I thought ` merged = [x for x in a + b if x not in merged]` would work, but it does not. set(a) seems more readable, as {} can be mistaken for dictionary notation.

Comment: Note that none of the examples here sort the numbers in the output list. A set is not sorted, so `[*set]` is not sorted. For small integers it **seems** sorted, but if you put larger numbers in, you'll notice it's not.